# Qualifications auditor should have to audit GIS

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, versioning, data-management

Background summary: Various systems are being audited and GIS is the next to be audited.  The initial kick-off for the audit was a meeting between me and a single auditor.  Initially, I thought it was going to be the typical security audit that is done for all RDBMS, which is fine.  That's good.  But then she said they would be executing a series of tests against our data (deletes, updates, inserts).

The geodatabase is versioned, so naturally I'm concerned.  When I received the meeting minutes from the auditor, I had to re-write it because the vocabulary was all wrong (lots of GIS words used in the wrong way/wrong order).

I'm not concerned about failing the audit--I'm worried about the auditors really mucking things up because they have no GIS experience.

Does anyone have experience with GIS audits and can provide some guidelines as to what qualifications the auditor (or audit team) should have?

Do internal audit departments typically have GIS professionals on staff?